# How can I preserve links between Word and Excel files across multiple computers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a Word file with linked images from several Excel files. All the files are in the same folder on a cloud drive.

As long as I'm on the computer where I created the links, they seem to behave as expected, e.g. I can right-click and update them with the current Excel content.

When I open the same Word file on another computer, the links are gone and they act like static images.

To be clear, I am not moving or copying any files, just opening the same file in the same folder. There's no error message or any other hint of what the issue is. This is Office 365 on both computers. Windows 11 on the first one and Windows 10 on the second one.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this so that the links can be updated from different computers?

Comment: It should work if the path is identical; it won't if it isn't.

Comment: OK but if if it isn't, is this the expected behavior? Just no link at all, rather than a broken one?

Comment: How are you creating the link (in-line plain-text/auto-format?  Inserting as object?  Formulaic?), and how are they formatted (absolute vs relative, etc?  For [reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats))?

Comment: I'm creating the link by copying the cell range in Excel, then back to Word and Paste Special > Paste Link > Bitmap. And thanks for the reference -- I have some experience with changing the file path in Excel, e.g. linking to one workbook from another. But I would do that right in the formula bar, or in the Name Manager. I don't know the equivalent tool in Word where the file path is exposed for editing?

Comment: See Paul Edstein (macropod)'s tutorial on Relative a Paths in fields. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Word and Excel files should be placed under the same folder, otherwise their links will go wrong, and will the links become invalid after downloading the files locally?